# How to set variable range for Slider2D in DynamicModule?

Tags: dynamic

I would like to have a Slider2D for a variable x but at the same time I have RadioButtonBar for another variable U. I want the Slider2D's range to change as I change U.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work. I assume I miss some basic knowledge here I might use DynamicWrapper or something else.

````
edges = Which[
   U == 1., 4,
   U == 10., 6,
   U == 100., 10,
   U == 1000., 23,
   U == 10000., 45,
   U == 100000., 100
   ];

DynamicModule[{x, U}, {

  Text@Item["U=" Dynamic@U], 
  RadioButtonBar[Dynamic@U, {1., 10., 100.}],
  Slider2D[Dynamic[x], {{0, 0}, {edges, edges}}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]

  }]
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make edges a function and wrap the second argument in `DynamicModule` with `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{x, U = 1.}, Dynamic @ 
 {Text@Item["U=" Dynamic[U]], 
   RadioButtonBar[Dynamic@U, {1., 10., 100.}], 
   Slider2D[Dynamic[x], {{0, 0}, {edges@U, edges@U}}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]}, 
 Initialization :> {edges[U_] := Which[U == 1., 4, U == 10., 6, U == 100., 10, U == 1000., 23, 
     U == 10000., 45, U == 100000., 100]}]
```

[image]